# How to fine tune the redundant code in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create two set of databases every time inside my python script for the same of which I have written the below set of code which looks redundant to me since I am initializing the variable `ext` 2 times and hence if anyone can suggest some better alternatives, that would be really helpful.

```
def create_datasets(database, ext):
    try:
        dataset = "bq --location=US mk -d " + database + ext

        try:
            return_cd, out, err = run_sys_command(dataset)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise

ext = ''
create_datasets(database, ext)
ext = '_stg'
create_datasets(database, ext)
```

Comment: Why create a variable? just pass the string.

Comment: `create_datasets(database, '')`  then `create_datasets(database, '_stg')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop?

```
for ext in ['', '_stg']:
    create_datasets(database, ext)
```

About your function:

```
def create_datasets(database, ext):
    try:
        dataset = f"bq --location=US mk -d {database}{ext}"
        return_cd, out, err = run_sys_command(dataset)
    except Exception as e:  # <- you should catch sub exception!
        print(e)
```

Comment: Hello, may i know what do you mean by "you should catch sub exception!" . I am already catching it right? Even i have the catch statement in place if you see.

Comment: You are catching _any_ exception. You should be more specific about what type of exception you're handling.

Answer (score 1):

Any exception `Exception` raised in your function is caught and handled by the inner try block. The outer therefore seems redundant.

```
def create_datasets(database, ext):
    try:
        dataset = "bq --location=US mk -d " + database + ext
        return_cd, out, err = run_sys_command(dataset)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```